# How to resolve an Error installing NLTK packages in Heroku

Tags: heroku, text, download, nltk, wordnet

I am facing the below error while deploying a text analysis app on Heroku.

> [nltk_data] Error loading wordnet : Package 'wordnet\r' not found in
> [nltk_data]     index

I do have a nltk.txt file with wordnet mentioned in it. Can someone help me with this?